# How do I remove this offset from the top?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, multicolumn, vertical-spacing, vspace

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,oneside]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath,pifont,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
%captiondelim{. }

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{#1. }
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{3}{\parindent}%
                                     {4ex\@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {4ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{3}{2.5cm}%
                                     {4ex\@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {4ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{3.75cm}%
                                     {4ex\@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {4ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
                                     \renewcommand\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} #2\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{CustomTable}{#2#1\\#3}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fill}{\hfill}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{fullparents}{\bothIfFirst{#1}{~}#2}
\captionsetup[table]{
     format=CustomTable,
     font={normalsize},
     labelformat=fullparents,
     labelsep=fill,
     justification=centering,
     singlelinecheck=false,
     skip=0pt
     }
     \theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Определение}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Следствие}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Лемма}

\sloppy
\begin{document}

\textbf{Решение}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Гамильтониан: $H = \psi_1 v + \psi_2 (\frac{uF}{M} - g)$
\item Уравнения Эйлера-Лагранжа:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\[
        \begin{cases}
            \psi^{\prime}_1 = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial h}\\
            \psi^{\prime}_2 = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial v}\\
        \end{cases}
\]
\columnbreak
\[
        \begin{cases}
            \psi^{\prime}_1 = 0\\
            \psi^{\prime}_2 = -\psi_1\\
        \end{cases}
\]
\columnbreak    
\[
        \begin{cases}
            \psi_1 = C_1\\
            \psi_2 = -C_1 t + C_2\\
        \end{cases}
\]
\end{multicols}
\item  Условие принципа максимума Понтрягина:
$$maxH = max(\psi_1 v + \psi_2 (\frac{uF}{M} - g)) = \psi_1 v - \psi_2 g + max(\psi_2\frac{uF}{M})$$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I remove this offset from the top?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE that we can copy and paste. Add documentclass and used packages as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Unknown updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minimal working example is incomplete. Nevertheless I managed to reproduce the error.
You have to add a `\noindent` at the beginning of the first column.

Over all the way via multicol is in my opinion rather inconvenient. Therefore, I put all that simply into parboxes

```
\begin{enumerate} 

\item DEF: $H = \psi_1 v + \psi_2 (\frac{uF}{M} - g)$ 
\item 123 456:\\
\parbox[c]{0.4\linewidth}{
\[
\begin{cases}
\psi^{\prime}_1 = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial h}\\ \psi^{\prime}_2 = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial v} \end{cases}
\] 
}\parbox[c]{0.3\linewidth}{
\[ 
\begin{cases} \psi^{\prime}_1 = 0\\ \psi^{\prime}_2 = -\psi_1 
\end{cases} \] 
}\parbox[c]{0.3\linewidth}{
\[ 
\begin{cases} \psi_1 = C_1\\ \psi_2 = -C_1 t + C_2 
\end{cases} \]
}%parbox
\item GHI JKL MNO PQR: $$maxH = max(\psi_1 v + \psi_2 (\frac{uF}{M} - g)) = \psi_1 v - \psi_2 g + max(\psi_2\frac{uF}{M})$$ 
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 1):

You not need `multicols` nor `parbox` environments. Just write equation in one row and with `\qquad` make gaps between `cases`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item DEF: $H = \psi_1 v + \psi_2 (\frac{uF}{M} - g)$
\item 123 456:\\
\[
\begin{cases}
\psi^{\prime}_1 = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial h}\\ 
\psi^{\prime}_2 = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial v} 
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases} 
\psi^{\prime}_1 = 0\\ 
\psi^{\prime}_2 = -\psi_1
\end{cases} 
\qquad
\begin{cases} 
\psi_1 = C_1\\ 
\psi_2 = -C_1 t + C_2
\end{cases} 
\]
\item GHI JKL MNO PQR: 
\[
\max{H} = \max(\psi_1 v + \psi_2 \biggl(\frac{uF}{M} - g)\biggr)
        = \psi_1 v - \psi_2 g + \max\biggl(\psi_2\frac{uF}{M}\biggr)
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

In the MWE above, I corrected the last equation as I think it should be written correctly.

[image]